# Как конвертировать JSON в VARCHAR[]?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Есть таблица с полем типа `JSON`. Появилась необходимость перенести данные этой таблицы в новую, где у поля имеется другой тип - `VARCHAR[]`.

Попытался перенести данные "грубо", но тут же словил ошибку:

```
ERROR: malformed array literal: "{{"value","value"},{"value","value","value"}}"
DETAIL: Multidimensional arrays must have sub-arrays with matching dimensions.
```

Но при этом часть данных была перенесена. Просто в один момент почему-то упало.

Посмотрел и обнаружил что в таблице в поле пишутся только записи вида `{1,2,3}` или `{{1,2,3}}`, но нет чего-то похожего на это `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}`. Ну то есть об этом и ошибка по сути.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как же мне все-таки перенести эти данные, как правильно конвертировать данные при переносе?

Comment: Вероятно вложенные массивы должны иметь одинаковое количество элементов. А у Вас первый имеет 2, а второй 3 элемента. Было бы например {{"value","value"},{"value","value"}}. Так что смотрите что каким образом из json в массив перегоняете. Это разные структуры и далеко не всегда можно сопоставить json и массив.

Comment: @Sergey получается, если я хочу иметь разное кол-во элементов, то надо оставаться на json типе?

Comment: Можно конечно извратиться и с массивом. Но json лучше, правильнее. Так же xml хорош. А массив очень плох для этого.

Comment: @Sergey понял вас. Спасибо.

Comment: А для чего переводите в `VARCHAR[]`? Какие операции делаете над ними? Потому что если только храните и достаёте, а в условиях не используете, то даже `json` достаточно.

Comment: @D-side на минуту показалось, что `VARCHAR[]` будет правильней. Но как оказалось, в данном случае `JSON` в самый раз.